# Unable to access a file on second call to same function in c#

Tags: c#

I am writing to a file through a function. On the first call I am able to write to the file but on the second call I get an exception:

> The process cannot access a file because it is being used by some other process.

Basically the function I am calling starts a `System.Diagnostics.Process` process whose output I have to write to a file with the same name and location each time the function gets called. But whenever the function gets called for the second time I get the exception.

I have tried

```
Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(contents);
if (!File.Exists(fileName))
{
    // Create the file. 
    using (FileStream fs = File.Create(fileName))
    {
        fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
        fs.Close();
    }
}

using (FileStream file_write = File.Open(fileName,FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    file_write.Write(info,0,info.Length);
    file_write.Close();
}
```

and

```
File.writealltext(filename,contents)
```

and

```
using (StreamWriter file_write = new StreamWriter(File_path))
{
    file_write.WriteLine(File_data);
    file_write.Close();
}
```

Nothing worked.
Can anyone suggest any other way of doing this I am really stuck.

Comment: Try Closing the file if it is opened, before start working on that.

Comment: Tried it already didn't work

Comment: Can you post exception stack trace ?

Comment: FileStream fileStream = null;

try
{
    fileStream =
        new FileStream(@"c:\file.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write);
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
{
    // The access requested is not permitted by the operating system
    // for the specified path, such as when access is Write or ReadWrite
    // and the file or directory is set for read-only access. 
}
finally
{
    if (fileStream != null)
        fileStream.Close ();
}             Try something like this.

Comment: Can you post the code that is creating the Process and how it's output is being passed into your example above. If you are calling Start on the Process you will want to try calling WaitForExit afterwards so you can make sure that the first Process has finished.

Comment: can you share the code of how you are calling the method 2 times.because the error is like after your first usage,you were not closing that file before calling again.

Comment: process.StartInfo.FileName = _process_name; process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(_process_name);
process.StartInfo.Arguments = _arguments;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                process.Start();
                log.Warn(_process_name + " Started " + process.StartTime.ToLongTimeString());
                _read_output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                writeFile(_process_log, _read_output);
                process.WaitForExit(3600000);

Comment: I am calling it in a loop

Comment: Is it a multi-threaded application? If so can you check that the first process has finished writing it's output to the file before the second call is made?

Comment: No it happens in a single thread. The function is called in a loop.

Comment: Would you be willing to share the solution that is going wrong so we could help diagnose the issue?

Comment: See I give a call to a function. Say xyz(processname,arguments) now xyz(string name, string arguments){1.] create a new process 2.] write output of process to a file 3.] close the process. Now xyz is called in a loop so this happens in a loop. For first tikme as no process is accessing the file i am abke to access it but from second call onwards I am gettting exceptions. This is because my the first call hasn't freed the file. So how to free the file so that on the second call the function can access it.

Comment: I would not suggest this as a complete solution but to test can you try calling process.Kill() at the end of your loop? Also keep an eye on Task manager to check that the process is actually closing down. Your using and close statements should be handling the closing down of the file access.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use lock so that way the processes will wait for each other to finish writing.

```
static object obj = new object();
            static void WriteOnFile(byte[] data)
            { 
                lock(obj)
                {
                  FileStream file_write = new FileStream(ileName,FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                  file_write.Write(data,0,data.Length);
                  file_write.Close();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Are you using the same process two times or two different processes?
This works only when you use the same process.

Comment: As the function is called again a new process gets created again.